# SecureString's length is 0 when sent to a webapi controller

Tags: c#, webapi, securestring

I am trying to send a SecureString to a web api controller, but it is always giving me a length of 0 at the controller's part.

Here's the client's side:

[image: Here's the client's side]

As you can see, it has a non-zero length at the time of serialization. By the time the controller gets it, it's 0.

Here's the controller's side

[image: Here's the controller's side]

Everything else that's needed gets set correctly. It's not null, but the length is 0.

Comment: SecureString is not serializable (by purpose)

Comment: and isn't recommended for usage anymore

Comment: What can I do then? my WPF has a passwordbox

Comment: `PasswordBox` has a `Password` property; using the `SecurePassword` property is not mandatory, as far as I know. There is no point  in trying to keep the password as a `SecureString` if it's going to be sent out over the wire; it will likely pass through many layers of code that will not try to ensure the password is never copied anywhere in memory. (This is the main reason `SecureString` is no longer recommended; it's just not realistic. You are better off investing in securing the machine as a whole.)

Comment: But, is there a reason that the object is getting sent, but is getting erased?

Comment: I doubt it's getting sent at all (unless you can show otherwise with a packet dump). You're just getting a default (empty) instance of a `SecureString`.